# MUI's Autocomplete AS MULTIPLE input + react-hook-form + controlling default values not working (TypeError: Can't read property 'filter' of undefined)

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am trying to use `Material-UI Autocomplete` as multiple input with `react-hook-form` and `control` the `defaultValues` of the Autocomplete dynamically (render the component prefilled, when editing data, based on already saved data fetched from a database).

**So the main question is:**

What is the best way to control the default values in an `Material-UI Autocomplete` component and use it with `react-hook-form`?

**What i did so far:**

1. With using functions and hooks in react, I have wrapped an
   Autocomplete component in React Hook Form's `Controller` to control
   the state. I tried to implemented the solutions from the docs of MUI
   and `react-hook-form` and the solutions of the below threads.

   [**I created a minimal Sandbox here**](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-multiple-autocomplete-react-hook-form-with-controlled-default-value-minimal-example-6bm53?file=/src/App.js:178-306)

**What it does**

When i set the `defaultValue` in `Controller`, it works to display the controlled default value, but throws me an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`

```
  <Controller
      as={
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        value={defaultValues}
        onChange={(e, values) => setValue("food", values)}
        ...
        renderInput={params => ( ... )}
      />
    }
    control={control}
    name="food"
    defaultValue={defaultValues} // <- this makes the error
  />
```

When i don't set the `defaultValue` in `Controller`, it works perfectly to being able to select `multiple` values like expected, but it doesn't show the default value.

What is so confusing is, that the `Autocomplete` has to be controlled with `value/onChange` and also the `Controller` has to control with `defaultValue/setValue`, and it seems they conflict in my case.

2. It works better when setting `defaultValue={ [] }` and using a
   `useEffect` and controlling the default value only with
   `setValue("food", defaultOption);`

   [**So i created another Sandbox here**](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-multiple-autocomplete-react-hook-form-with-controlled-default-value-minimal-example-with-only-setvalue-crmph?file=/src/App.js)
3. **Thanks to Bill's answer i refactored the code to a renderProp
   like proposed in the docs:**

   [**Yet another sandbox here**](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-multiple-autocomplete-react-hook-form-with-controlled-default-value-minimal-example-with-renderprop-reoul?file=/src/App.js)

   Now it  works like a charm, but i had to set the `onChange` prop of
   the `Autocomplete` like this:

   `onChange={(e, values) => setValue("food", values)}`

   instead of what the docs proposed to do:  (using the passed onChange)

   `onChange={e => props.onChange(e.something)}`

   It works, but is this the right way to combine `Autocomplete` and
   `react-hook-form`?

**Compare the questions with these threads:**

The main difference to the other threads i am trying to do, is to set the `defaultValues` of a `multiple Autocomplete`.

[Proper way to use react-hook-form Controller with Material-UI Autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61655199/proper-way-to-use-react-hook-form-controller-with-material-ui-autocomplete)

[MUI Autocomplete's 'defaultValue' not working when used with Controller of react-hook-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62510884/mui-autocompletes-defaultvalue-not-working-when-used-with-controller-of-react)

[Why is initial value not set in Material UI Autocomplete using react-hook-form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60107068/why-is-initial-value-not-set-in-material-ui-autocomplete-using-react-hook-form)

The advised solution in the docs of `react-hook-form`:

https://react-hook-form.com/api/#Controller

And the Code from `Material UI` docs:

https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#multiple-values

Comment: consider using render prop if you are on V6.

Comment: Here is a working code example for multiple and react-hook-forms: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/reareact-hook-form-with-mui-examples-a3080b71ec45

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this working by doing the following:

```
                                <Controller
                                    name='test'
                                    control={control}
                                    render={({onChange, ...props}) => (
                                        <AutoComplete
                                            {...props}
                                            data-testid='test-select'
                                            width={350}
                                            label='Auto Complete'
                                            onChange={onChange}
                                            options={eventTypes}
                                            getOptionLabel={(option) => option ? option.name : ''}
                                            renderOption={(option) => option.name }
                                            getOptionSelected={(option) => option.name}
                                            renderInput={(params) => (
                                                <TextField {...params} error={error} helperText={helperText} label={label} placeholder={label} />
                                            )}
                                            onChange={(e, data) => onChange(data)}
                                            {...props}
                                        />
                                    )}
                                />
```

Comment: However, I've not found a way to validate this using react-hook-form

Comment: Do u using two `onChange` attributes in Autocomplete component and haven't error?

Answer (score 1):

> However, I've not found a way to validate this using react-hook-form

You could try custom validation (in case if you are using MUI's Autocomplete with multiple={true}):

```
<Controller
...
rules={{
   validate: (data) => {
     if(data.length === 0) return false;
   }
}}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Now it works like a charm, but i had to set the onChange prop of the
> Autocomplete like this:
>
> `onChange={(e, values) => setValue("food", values)}`

You can do `onChange={(e, newValue) => props.onChange(newValue)}`