# ReactJS + Material-UI Autocomplete defaultValue not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I followed the same pattern mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63149959/muis-autocomplete-as-multiple-input-react-hook-form-controlling-default-val) but the difference is I'm passing the 'options' as 'props.CountryList' from another component. Can someone please let me know what are the changes I need to do when I pass the 'options' as a props ?

Comment: Please share a codesandbox so we can work together at the same code.

Comment: @bertdida : Here is the sample codesandbox : Would be great if you can help me on this 

https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-snyder-q22gj

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an empty array as `defaultValue` value in your `Controller` - then you are using that as the `value` for `Autocomplete`. I also don't think you need the `defaultValue` in `Autocomplete`.

Anyways, the code below should work

```js
export default function AutoSelect({ options, selectedValue }) {
  const { control, setValue } = useForm();

  if (options.length === 0) {
    return null;
  }

  const defaultValue = options.find((i) => i.value === selectedValue);

  return (
    <Controller
      render={(props) => (
        <Autocomplete
          options={options}
          getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
          value={props.value}
          onChange={(e, values) => setValue("food", values)}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              label="Choose food"
              name={props.name}
              placeholder="Choose food"
              variant="outlined"
              fullWidth
            />
          )}
        />
      )}
      control={control}
      name="food"
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
    />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit suspicious-bartik-qlkp2]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. Still defaultValue is not showing. I'm calling separate two APIs to get the  "options" and  "selectedValue". May be the autocomplete component render before selectedValue (defaultValue) is set ? Already spent one day on this , no luck :(

Comment: @shalinds that's weird. I think the issue is on you `Parent` component. I updated the codesandbox to simulate the API call. Please check it out.

Comment: Seems something wrong with the Parent component. I copied the exact CodeSandbox sample and pasted in my solution , DeafultValue is not displaying. In Parent component I have 10-15 sub components which calls different APIs and it take sometime to load data too,as mentioned AutoComplete component is getting render before I set the DeafultValue it seems

Comment: Yea. That's why (if you notice),  I rendered a loading spinner while API call is not resolved yet, this avoids rendering `AutoComplete` component while fetching is still in progress.