# React: MUI autocomplete input controlled with react-hook-form `<controller>` component does not work when props `multiple` is set to `true`

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, autocomplete, react-hook-form

I'm currently having issues with controlling an autocomplete MUI component with react-hook-form's `<controller>` component.

Here's the code:

```js
<Controller
  control={control}
  name="rooms"
  render={({ field }) => (
    <Autocomplete
      multiple
      limitTags={6}
      // data is formatted like this: [{label: string, value: number}]
      options={data}
      filterSelectedOptions
      style={{ minWidth: '350px', maxWidth: '30%' }}
      renderInput={params => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          variant="outlined"
          label="Rooms"
          placeholder="Search"
        />
      )}
      {...field}
    />
  )}
/>
```

Here's my issue: When setting up a controller element on it, the returned value on the submition of our form will always be `0` for some reason.

**Example:** I'm selecting two  rooms, `Bathroom`(with id 1) and `Kitchen`(with id 0). The expected output would be: `rooms: [{label: 'Bathroom', value: 1}, {label: 'Kitchen', value: 0}]` but i'm getting `rooms: 0` instead.

[There's another forum on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63149959/muis-autocomplete-as-multiple-input-react-hook-form-controlling-default-val), however it has been unactive for over two years, and none of the given answers seem to work.

Here's my packages versions:

- react-hook-form (*7.43.9*)
- @material-ui/core (*4.12.4*)

Thanks in advance for your help and advices !

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer. The problem was how I wrote my render props:

**Here's the functionnal render code:**

```js
render={({ field }) => {
  const { onChange, onBlur, value } = field;
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      multiple
      limitTags={6}
      options={data}
      filterSelectedOptions
      style={{ minWidth: '350px', maxWidth: '30%' }}
      renderInput={params => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          variant="outlined"
          label="Rooms"
          placeholder="Search"
        />
      )}
      onChange={(event, selectedOptions) => {
        onChange(selectedOptions);
      }}
      onBlur={onBlur}
      value={value}
    />
  );
}}
```

**Explanation of the issue:**

I was only passing the field object to the `<Autocomplete>` component, which means I was not updating the `value` correctly. By destructuring the `onChange`, `onBlur`, and `value` from the field object and passing them to the corresponding props of `<Autocomplete>`, it is ensuring that the selected options are properly updated and stored in the form's state when using `react-hook-form`.